# How to solve java runtime error in for loops

Tags: java

This Java code works well in my IDE but it shows runtime error when I put in online judge system.

It would be great if you help me through to solve this error. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num1;
        int num2;
        Scanner dev = new Scanner(System.in);
        num1 = dev.nextInt();
        num2 = dev.nextInt();

        int numa;
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        for (numa = num1; numa <= 100; numa++) {
            if (numa % num1 == 0) {
                sb1.append(numa).append(",");
            }
        }
            sb1.deleteCharAt(sb1.length() - 1);
            System.out.print(sb1);

        int numb;
        System.out.println();
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
        for (numb = num2; numb <= 100; numb++) {
            if (numb % num2 == 0) {
                sb2.append(numb).append(",");
            }
        }
            sb2.deleteCharAt(sb2.length() - 1);
            System.out.print(sb2);

        int numc;
        System.out.println();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (numc = num1; numc <= 100; numc++) {
            if (numc % num1 == 0 && numc % num2 == 0) {
                sb.append(numc).append(",");
            }
        }
            sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
            System.out.print(sb);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the actual error? when does it occur?

Comment: It just shows that run time error occurs and nothing else.

Comment: Please add the concrete error message and its stack trace.

Comment: What is the error? Runtime or Time Limit Exceeded? please describe it.

Comment: At the end, enclose  `sb.length() - 1` in parentheses: `(sb.length() - 1)`. The line should be: `sb.deleteCharAt((sb.length() - 1));`. Or use the StringBuilder#toString() method: `sb.deleteCharAt(sb.toString().length() - 1);`

Comment: Probably worth checking that `sb.length() > 0`

Comment: Try run you code with `101 101` input and you'll get that error locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you want to append the result of below blocks of code

```
for (numa = num1; numa <= 100; numa++) {
                if (numa % num1 == 0) {
                    sb1.append(numa).append(",");
                }
            }
```

into

```
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
```

But for any number greater than **100** this block of code doesn't get executed. So **sb1** contains value **null** or **empty string** so when program try to do `sb1.deleteCharAt(sb1.length() - 1);` it throws runtime exception as the length of sb1 is 0 and the program is trying to delete the character from **length - 1** index which is **-1** in this case. And that is the reason for runtime exception.
This is true for remaining 2 for loop also.

Please try to replace the code `sb1.deleteCharAt(sb1.length() - 1);` with below code.

```
if(sb1.length() > 1) {
  sb1.deleteCharAt(sb1.length() - 1);
}
```

I hope it will help you solve the issue you're facing. If it doesn't help please provide the problem statement that you're trying to solve so that I can try to give best possible solution for it.